# Llamar a un amigo o un conocido "macho"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, españa, sustantivos

¿Cuál es el significado de "macho" cuando un hombre llama a otro hombre (que puede ser un amigo o un conocido) con este término en España? Por ejemplo, "oye, macho, ¿vendrás con nosotros luego?".  ¿Es posible que una mujer llame a otro hombre con este término también?

Comment: Interesante pregunta.  Para hombres es simplemente otra versión de *hombre* / *tío* / *tronco*.  De una mujer a un hombre lo he escuchado así que no te voy a decir que no exista, pero no es tan frecuente.

Comment: @間羽原他 - Ah, interesante.  Así es hoy día entre los jóvenes en EEUU con "dude," que antes era nomás para los varones.

Comment: Yo pienso que esto puede variar por los diferentes países hispanohablantes. No me suena mucho el uso de esta expresión en España por ejemplo, pero en México, el uso es muy común. Favor de clarificar en qué parte del mundo hispanohablante estás averiguando o en todos...

Comment: Definitivamente esta pregunta tiene una fuerte componente regional. Para mí "macho" se usa como "tío" pero tiene una connotación ligeramente negativa. La usaría en frases como "venga, macho, decídete ya" y similares. Me hace gracia que la versión femenina sea "guapa": "oye, guapa, ¿pero tú quién te has creído?".

Comment: En Costa Rica "macho" o "macha" significa "rubio" ;)

Comment: @Charlie - Con *guapa* se oye sarcastico.  Es asi tambien con *macho*?

Comment: @aparente001 yo diría que sí, pero tal vez no de forma tan acusada, pero esto es una percepción personal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues como ya ha sido mencionado en los comentarios, *"macho"* se usa de manera informal para referirse a alguien. Al igual que *"hombre", "tío"*, o como dicen las juventudes *"chaval"*, se suele usar para referirse a un amigo del sexo masculino, pero no es extraño usarlos para gente que no conoces bien pero con las que no hay necesidad de ser formal (por ejemplo, alguien que acabas de conocer en el bar), y también se puede usar para referirse a una mujer. La RAE da una definición que no parece estar de acuerdo con esto último de la mujer:

- macho: 7. m. coloq. U. para referirse a una persona del sexo masculino.

Aunque la gente te entendería, yo intentaría no usarlo mucho en Andalucía y, sobre todo, en Canarias. Siendo de Canarias me suena rarísimo cuando alguien usa "macho". Nosotros solemos usar "chacho" con el mismo significado, pero hay mucha gente a la que no le gusta cuando alguien que no es canario lo usa.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus aportaciones!